# CRUD App: Getting IDs to delete and update records

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to create a very simple CRUD App and I am unsure what's the best way to update and delete records. I am able to successfully list all records and create a new record. Now I would now like to delete these records through the app and it is not immediately clear on how I should do it.

Let's say I have a Person table with just one field Name like so:

```
Person 
   name Text
```

I have a handler called PersonR that lists all the persons in the table and a form to input a new one. For handling delete and update, I thought I can create a hidden field called  `personId`  and then process the form through an InputForm but I couldn't get the ID out easily. I tried  `unKey personId`  but it still has  `PersistInt64 1` so I am presuming this is not the right way to go about it even if I manage to fish the ID out of there.

Another approach I could take is create a new handler (say ListPersons) just to list all persons and then change the  `Person` handler to  `Person/#personId.` I prefer to avoid this if possible and keep all actions related to Person in one place if possible.

Could you please let me know if I am thinking about this right and any suggestions for implementing a basic CRUD App functionality?

**Update**: I ended up creating a  `PersonPanel` which will handle GET and POST. The `Person` Handler took care of DELETE and PUT. I ended up putting the 4 Handlers in the same Person handler file so it is not scattered around. Hope this helps others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `toPathPiece` in `Web.PathPieces.PathPiece` class to convert a key to `Text`, and putting it into a hidden field?

I guess yesod uses this class to convert a key to `Text` when it encodes the key into a type-safe URL, and vice versa.

Even though you can convert a key to `Text` in this way, a preferred way would be sending a DELETE request to `Person/#personId`. You can generate this URL using `@{...}` in your hamlet template.

Comment: Thanks @snak. It sort of looked like sending Delete to Person/#personId may be the best way to go about it. The only issue with this approach is I will end up having 2 handlers working on the same table -- one to get (all) / post entities and the other to delete and update them. Seems a bit unintuitive to me. If no one else has a better suggestion, I will accept your answer. 

As you mentioned, I will probably avoid toPathPiece simply because I don't know much Haskell and probably should stick to well documented approaches :)